# Meaning of 'were it not that'?

Tags: meaning

> Many of the children who are employed as helpers, messengers, cash
>   boys and minor laborers in shops, foundries, factories, offices and as
>   venders, are the mainstay of families that live, God knows how, for
>   the one who should be the bread winner is an invalid, a cripple, a
>   paralytic, and would be in the charity hospital or the almshouse **were
>   it not that the instinct of family unity is as strong and admirable
>   among the humble as among the rich.**

I don't understand what "were it not that" & the last part mean. Does it mean that "it's not because that the instinct of poor families are as strong as the rich families, but thanks to the children, poor families are able to live"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could translate it also as "thanks to the".

> Many of the children who are employed as helpers, messengers, cash
>   boys and minor laborers in shops, foundries, factories, offices and as
>   venders, are the mainstay of families that live, God knows how, for
>   the one who should be the bread winner is an invalid, a cripple, a
>   paralytic, and would be in the charity hospital or the almshouse, **but thanks**
>   **to the** strong and admirable instinct of family unity ...

But in this case "were it not that" sounds a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

The disabled parents would be in the almshouse **if it were not for the fact that** the instinct of family unity **is** as strong in poor families as in rich ones.